# Freude, Genuss, Lust, Vergnügen

Tags: synonym

I am trying to understand the exact differences between the most common words which may mean "pleasure" in German: Freude, Genuss, Lust and Vergnügen.

My understanding so far:

- Freude: pleasure resulting from a state of happiness (having a good life), a pleasing activity (eg from seeing an old friend, graduating in college,  going to a party, traveling to another country). Also used politely in work activities (to meet a new client)
- Genuss: immediate pleasure resulting from a sensorial feeling (eg from drinking a wine, eating a dish, hearing a music, watching a movie, having sex)
- Lust : same usage of Freude + sex context (more usual than the others terms in this context)
- Vergnügen: same usage of Freude + sex context

Are those right? Some examples for discussion and my guesses:

Mein Lebensstil macht mir Freude / Lust / Vergnügen ( = My life style brings me pleasure)

Es ist mir eine Freude / Lust / Vergnügen, Sie in meinem neuen Haus begrüßen zu dürfen. (= It is a pleasure to welcome you in my new house.)

Die Freude / Genuss / Lust / Vergnügen, einen guten Wein zu trinken, ist einzigartig (= The pleasure of drinking a good wine is unique.)

Sie hat keine Genuss / Lust / Vergnügen mehr mit ihm beim Sex.
( = She doesn't feel pleasure anymore with him during sex.)

The other meanings of these words are out of the scope of this question.

Comment: *Lust* and *Vergnügen* aren't sex-related in German.

Comment: Lust can be sex related. The verb vergnügen can also be sex related.

Comment: The noun Vergnügen also can be sex related according to linguee.com: https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/sexual+pleasure.html . However, it is not so usual indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Freude**
This is a very general word to express happiness over something. Common examples would be

> Was eine Freude Dich zu sehen! (Literally: What a pleasure to see you.)
>   Es ist mir eine Freude Dir zu helfen. (Literally: It's a pleasure for me to help you.)
>   Dein Geschenk hat mir große Freude bereitet. (Your present was a big delight for me).

Note that the idiomatic expression would be "Freude bereiten".

Often these constructions are replaced by the verb "sich freuen":

> Ich freue mich, Dich zu sehen
>   Ich freue mich, Dir zu helfen.
>   Ich habe mich sehr über dein Geschenk gefreut. (I was delighted about your gift).

**Genuss**
As you mentioned, this is associated with sensory input. It can be used in sexual context however that would not be my first association. I think it is more commonly used with foods, art and views/scenery. Again, phrases are more common with the verb "genießen".

> Ich genieße den Ausblick. (I enjoy the view)
>   Genieß dein Wochenende! (Enjoy your weekend).
>   Wann komme ich mal wieder in den Genuss einer deiner Massagen? (When will I be able to enjoy one of your massages again?)

The last example uses the idiomatic expression "in den Genuss von etwas kommen" (etwas is a Genitiv object).

**Lust**
Lust has different meanings depending on context. "Lust haben" can be used to express the intention of doing/not doing something

> Ich habe Lust ein Eis zu essen. (I'd like to eat some ice cream)
>   Ich hätte Lust nach Berlin zu fahren. (I'd like to go to Berlin)
>   Ich habe keine Lust den Geschirrspüler auszuräumen. (I don't want to empty the dish washer)
>   Ich habe Lust auf Dich! (I'm hot for you/I want you)

On the other hand, Lust can also have the meaning of lust (English)

> Die Lust in ihm wuchs an. (He became more horny).
>   Man sah die Lust in ihren Augen. (You could see the lust in her eyes).

**Vergnügen**
Vergnügen also has a non-sexual and a sexual context, although the latter is mainly used as the verb *sich vergnügen*.

> Es bereitet mir großes Vergnügen, Dir beim Klavierspielen zuzuhören. (It brings me great joy to listen to you playing the piano)
>   Lass uns in den Vergnügungspark gehen! (Let's go to the amusement park!)
>   In der Kanalisation zu arbeiten ist wahrlich kein Vergnügen. (Working in the sewers is fairly unpleasant).
>   Adam und Eva vergnügten sich im Sonnenuntergang. (Adam and Eve enjoyed themselves during sunset. Here it's clearly sexual)

**Your sentences**

> Mein Lebensstil macht mir Freude/Lust/Vergnügen ( = My life style brings me pleasure)

Here you would say *Mein Lebensstil bereitet mir Freude*. Lust and Vergnügen don't fit here.

> Es ist mir eine Freude/Lust/Vergnügen, Sie in meinem neuen Haus begrüßen zu dürfen. (= It is a pleasure to welcome you in my new house.)

The idiomatic expressions would be *Es ist mir eine Freude/ein Vergnügen*. Again, Lust does not fit.

> Die Freude/Genuss/Lust/Vergnügen, einen guten Wein zu trinken, ist einzigartig (= The pleasure of drinking a good wine is unique.)

Here Lust and Vergnügen don't fit. I would say it like this *Es ist eine einzigartige Freude / ein einzigartiger Genuss, einen guten Wein zu trinken.*

> Sie hat keinen Genuss/keine Lust/kein Vergnügen mehr mit ihm beim Sex. ( = She doesn't feel pleasure anymore with him during sex.)

This sentence feels a bit clumsy. Try theses alternatives:
*Sie empfindet keine Lust mehr mit ihm beim Sex.*
*Sie kann den Sex mit ihm nicht mehr genießen.*
*Sex mit ihm bereitet ihr kein Vergnügen mehr.*

Comment: "in den Genuss von etwas (Dative) kommen" or "in den Genuss etwas (Genitive) kommen" ?

Comment: Why "Vergnügen" does not fit in some examples where "Freude" is used (pleased with life style, pleasure to drink a wine)? I saw them as full synonyms, except in the sex context. Is there a difference in meaning or I have to learn usages case by case?

Comment: If that expression requires dative, why your example was "Wann komme ich mal wieder in den Genuss einer deiner Massagen? " ?

Comment: Because I can't speak my own language. Of course you're right, it's Genitiv, my apologies.

Comment: You can say: "In meinem Lebensstil habe ich viel Vergnügen." (In my lifestyle I experience a lot of pleasure". You might say "Es ist ein großes Vergnügen, einen guten Wein zu trinken", but for me that really implies that it's something that you like exceptionally much. I don't think many people would use it that way.

Comment: Kinder haben Lust auf Schokolade - wieso sollten Erwachsene nicht Lust haben, einen guten Wein zu trinken?

Comment: Natürlich haben Erwachsene Lust einen guten Wein zu trinken. Aber die Lust einen Wein zu trinken ist einzigartig, im Sinne von "The pleasure of drinking a good wine is unique" wäre eine fehlerhafte Übersetzung.

Comment: If "Vergnügen" in those sentences would imply that one "likes exceptionally much", may I assume that "Vergnügen" is a stronger feeling than "Freude"?

Comment: The most aligned English translations that I can think of for these explanations (which I think I'll try to remember them by) are "Freude" → "joy", "Genuss" → "pleasure", "Lust" → "desire" (wanting), and "Vergnügen" → "satisfaction".